# Amazon MWS endpoint to get all offers for an ASIN with PRICE and SELLER NAME of each Offer?

Tags: amazon-mws

I have a list of ASINs and I want to get the price of the offer from Amazon (if there is any).

I expect that there must be a MWS endpoint with which I can retrieve all offers for an ASIN. The Offer must have price and seller nam. Then I just loop the Offer data and search for Amazon as a seller for this offer.

Anyways I can't find any endpoint which does the job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get that kind of detail, you're going to need to subscribe to the [AnyOfferChangedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html) notification.